# Matrix thresholding by a threshold vector

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector, threshold

I have a numpy 2D array of shape [N,M] and a thresholds 1D array of shape M.
I want to set minus infinity value to every element in the 2D matrix, if the value in an index (X,i) (where X can be any row, X is between 0 and M-1) is lower than the value in the thresholding vector, in index i.

A non-loop or list-comprehension solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a snippet you can use...

```
data=np.random.rand(5,3)
threshold=np.random.rand(3)

data[data-threshold<0]=-np.Inf
```

I used random data to test, you don't need the first two lines if your data  already exists.